# Mongoose not updating password

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js

I'm trying to implement a 'reset password' feature in my project, I've successfully set it up so a user can enter their email, then a reset link gets sent with a `resetPasswordToken`, they click the link which  GETS `'/reset/:token` , then the POST for `'/reset/:token`  looks like this:

```
router.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
    async.waterfall([
      function(done) {
        User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
          if (!user) {
            req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
            return res.redirect('back');
          }
          if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
            user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
              user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
              user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
              user.save(function(err) {
                req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                  done(err, user);
                });
              });
            }) 
          } else {
              req.flash("error", "Passwords do not match.");
              return res.redirect('back');
          }
        });
      },
    ], function(err) {
      res.redirect('/');
    });
  });
```

My problem is that this code does not update the password in mongoDB. It logs the user in, but when I log out and use the 'new' password it doesn't work, but the old password does.

My code for signing a user up:

```
// if errors

else {
bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hashedPassword) => { 
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        } else {
          let theHash = hashedPassword;
          User.findOne({
            $or: [
              { username: { $regex: req.body.username, $options: "i" } },
              {
                businessName: { $regex: req.body.businessName, $options: "i" },
              },
            ],
          }).then((person) => {
            // if email or business exist, render with errors
            if (person) {
              res.render("signup", {
                emailTaken: "This email or business is already registered",
                info: req.body,
                errors: errorsObj,
                msg: "Please check the form for errors",
              });
            } else {
              // all good, create & save user
              const user = new User({
                businessName: req.body.businessName,
                username: req.body.username,
                password: theHash,
              });
              user.save(function (err) {
                if (err) {
                  return next(err);
                }
                // generate confirm account token and save
                var token = new Token({
                  _userId: user._id,
                  token: crypto.randomBytes(16).toString("hex"),
                });
                token.save(function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send({ msg: err.message });
                  }
                });
                // Send email (IRRELEVANT CODE)
                var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
                  service: "gmail",
                  auth: {
                    user: process.env.EMAIL,
                    pass: process.env.PASSWORD,
                  },
                });
                var mailOptions = {
                  from: process.env.EMAIL,
                  to: user.username,
                  subject: "Account Verification Link",
                  text:
                    "Hello " +
                    req.body.businessName +
                    ",\n\n" +
                    "Please verify your account by clicking the link: \nhttp://" +
                    req.headers.host +
                    "/confirmation/" +
                    user.username +
                    "/" +
                    token.token +
                    "\n\nThank You!\n",
                };

                transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send({
                      msg:
                        "Technical Issue!, Please click on resend for verify your Email.",
                    });
                  }
                  return res
                    .status(200)
                    .send(
                      "A verification email has been sent to " +
                        user.email +
                        ". It will be expire after one day. If you not get verification Email click on resend token."
                    );
                });

                //succesful - redirect to login with message
                res.redirect(
                  "/login/?message=" +
                    "Your account was created, please check your email for a verification link" + "&user=" + req.body.username
                );
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
```

I originally create the 'user' with this schema

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let UserSchema = new Schema({
    businessName: {type: String, required: true},
    username: {type: String, required: true},
    password: {type: String, required: true},
    isVerified: { type: Boolean, default: false },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date

});

UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose)


module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

I think the problem is coming from `user.setPassword` in the first block of code I provided,
because after that function gets called my user document in mongoDB now has these fields:

```
hash:"99f29724ca6591f581feb880d607f18445167d480075bab8b08197283fbdd6336f0c3d..."
salt:"2e5844ffb2557132ae22063fa88f73bad75708a23b9ce5a446854b069d42cb28"
```

I have never used the `.setPassword` function before but I'm guessing that's where those fields are coming from. So my question is how can I update the current password instead of creating the hash and salt fields? I've tried a few variations of mongoose .save() and .update() but haven't found the solution I need. I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Do you see anything if you `console.log(err)` as the first line within the `user.setPassword` callback? i.e. Right before you set `resetPasswordToken` to `undefined`. Does the callback even get invoked? I see in the [docs](https://github.com/saintedlama/passport-local-mongoose#api-documentation) `setPassword` takes 3 parameters (old password, new password, callback), not 2 — I'm thinking that's likely why.

Comment: `console.log(err)` returns `null`. I've tried modifying my code to `user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err, user) {` as well as `user.setPassword(user.password, req.body.password, function(err) {` and still no luck

Comment: turns out i was over complicating things and never needed the `.setPassword` function to begin with, i can simply hash the new `req.body.password` and updated with                       
` user.password = hashedPassword `. thanks for ur help!